# Growth of the gradient of $f(x+y) \leq f(x) f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-inequalities

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a radial continuous function and $C^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ which satisfies the following functional inequality

$$ f(x+y) \leq f(x) f(y) $$

Does there exist constants $c,d$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus\{ 0\}$ we have
$$ \vert \nabla f (x) \vert \leq c e^{d\vert x\vert} \quad (1)$$
In other words

> If $f$ solves $f(x+y) \leq f(x)f(y)$, does its gradient also grow at most exponentially? How about the Hessian?

In case we take $g(\vert x \vert)= f(x)$ and replace the inquality by an equality $g(r+s) = g(r) g(s)$ we get that $g(r) = e^{kr}$ for some $k$. Thus, in that case $f(x) = e^{k\vert x \vert}$. This function clearly satisfies the estimate $(1)$, as for $x\neq 0$
$$ \vert \nabla e^{k \vert x \vert} \vert = \left\vert \frac{kx}{\vert x \vert} e^{k\vert x \vert} \right\vert = \vert k \vert e^{k \vert x \vert}.$$
However, intuitively the function should be "less steep" when we take the functional inequality instead of the equality.

**Added:** In case it helps it would be fine if you assume $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: I think I can do this if we assume $f$ has directional derivatives at $0.$ Would that be useful?

Comment: @zhw. Sure, I'd love to hear anything that you can offer :)

Comment: @zhw. What was your idea to attack the problem?

Comment: I'll try to post something today or tomorrow.

Comment: Well ... I'm not quite able to do it. Some ideas I had didn't quite do the job. I'll continue to look at it, but no promises. Sorry about that.

Comment: @zhw. I did not mean to pressure you! I was simply curious. What was your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question can essentially be found in the answer of another question here [Derivatives of functions satisfying Euler-ish inequality $f(x+y)\le f(x)f(y)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385791/derivatives-of-functions-satisfying-euler-ish-inequality-fxy-le-fxfy/3385938?noredirect=1#comment6966277_3385938)

Many thanks to [@PhoemueX](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/151552/) and [@MaximilianJanisch](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631742/) (in particular for pointing out that we can actually smooth it without any problems).

Let me just give the main idea here. If we are in one dimension, then every function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $3 e^x \leq f(x) \leq 5 e^x$ solves the functional inequality as
$$ f(x+ y) \leq 5 e^{x+y} < (3 e^x)(3e^y) \leq f(x) f(y).  $$
(More generally: Any function $f$ that satisfies $c\cdot e^x\le f(x)\le c^2\cdot e^x$ for a constant $c\geq 1$ satisfies the functional inequality.)

Now we apply this idea to my problem. Hence, we pick a function $f$ as above, then $h(x):= f(\vert x \vert)$ will be radial and
$$ h(x+y) = f(\vert x +y \vert ) \leq 5 e^{\vert x + y \vert} < (3 e^{\vert x \vert})(3 e^{\vert y \vert}) \leq h(x) h(y). $$
We could almost pick the example from the other answer, namely
$$ f(x) = e^x (4 + \sin(e^{x^2})) $$
we would just need to smooth it slightely at the origin. For example
$$ g(x) = e^{\vert x \vert + (\vert x \vert^2 - \vert x \vert) \chi(\vert x \vert)} (4 + \sin(e^{\vert x \vert^2})) $$ 
with a cut-off function supported around the origin will work. In fact this function is smooth and alread the gradient will behave terribly. Of course we could make it worse by replacing $e^{\vert x \vert^2}$ in the sinus by something which grows even faster. This tells us that our gradient will not just be not bounded by some exponential, but we can make it arbitrarily bad.

**Added:** And, as Maximilian pointed out in the comment below, it works in any positive dimension.

Comment: As a bonus, this also works for any dimension